# License file directory on .NET Reactor

Tags: .net, net-reactor

I'm using an integrated build environment on Visual Studio and using the post build action to call .NET Reactor cmd.

Everything was working fine until I tried to change the license to another directory. If I use the following option on cmd: "-staticfilename c:\license.license" the application won't find the license file. 
Does someone knows if it's possible to place the license file on another directory and how to do so?

Comment: Use the vendor's support resources.

Comment: I already sent a mail to the vendor, but with no luck until now =(

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version you can also use special directories (MyDocuments etc.).

Comment: please avoid using screens if possible, paste the info as text instead.